# Retain Form:input value which gets value using ajax

Tags: javascript

For a form:input field I am selecting values from database using Ajax. I was not able to retain the value in the field after submitting the form. I need the same data for another submit.

Comment: Could you please past the code you are trying to debug ?

Comment: Please clear your question , I hope this might help you Use autocomplete in input element tag . Check This http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Answer (score 0):

The server you are posting to should set the value of the input element you're sending over (be sure to include the "name" attribute or the server won't get the field)  in the template that is rendered server side.

After you post a form to the server without Ajax, the page is refreshed and state is not preserved unless it was handled server side in the http response.